# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: javafx, gradle, java-home

I'm working with gradle and trying to deploy my JAVAFX application into .apk

If i run my gradle command it says that my JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.

It is set to C:\Program Files\Java\javaversion\bin
(there is an actual version actually, but it isn't necessery atm)
And the same is at the environment variable.

Any ideas, why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 8):

**What is JAVA_HOME?**

> Its an Environment variable that helps to locate JDK and JRE.

As you are setting it to.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\javaversion\bin
```

`JAVA_HOME` Should be set to root directory not upto bin

```
C:\Program Files\Java\javaversion
```

And in `path` variable put

```
C:\Program Files\Java\javaversion\bin OR %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

You can read more about from [This Link](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/environment_variables.html).

Comment: as for the path i need to use gradle, but trying out this one as we speak. I was given some advice that gradle may require installation of 32 bit java sdk, not 64bit as i have and needs to be in program files (x86) folder. I'm trying out this one after i've tried chaning the variable location.

Answer (score 4):

JAVA_HOME should be pointing one directory up, not at the bin directory

instead of

`C:\Program Files\Java\javaversion\bin`

use

`C:\Program Files\Java\javaversion`

Answer (score 1):

@charen You are right. Gradle, as of its last version 3.4.1, only works with Java 32 bits. So  your JAVA_HOME shoud point to the Java JRE at **Program Files (x86).**